# Can data ord be replaced with only RealFloat in comparing numbers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, functional-programming

```
maxs :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> a
maxs a b
    | a>b = a
    | otherwise = b


maxs :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
maxs a b
    | a>b = a
    | otherwise = b
```

I'm trying to write a max function using Haskell. These two seem to work both.  I wrote the first one and the latter one comes from the book. My question is, what's the difference between them? Can they replace each other?

The ord class is used for totally ordered datatypes. But in this case, order doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RealFloat` implies `RealFrac` which implies `Real` which in turn implies `Ord`.

In other words, every type that is an instance of `RealFloat` *must* also be an instance of `Ord`. So *both* of these functions require `Ord` (which is what defines the "`<`" operator that you're trying to use). But the first one pointlessly *also* requires a bunch of stuff to do with floating-point numbers (e.g., the `cos` function).

Order most certainly *does* matter; that's *the whole point* of a max function. It's to find the maximum value. Without an ordering, there *is* no maximum value!

By using `RealFrac`, on the other hand, you are prevented from (for example) finding the maximum `String`, since a `String` clearly isn't any kind of floating-point number.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now, the string thing answers my doubt :D

Answer (score 4):

Suppose I write two functions:

```
f :: (a, b) -> a
f (x, y) = x

g :: (Int, Bool) -> Int
g (x, y) = x
```

What is the difference? Function `g` is *less general* because its type is *more precise* than the type of `f`. In a sense `g` is "artificially restricted" to work only on `(Int, Bool)` when it could work on any product type.

The situation with your two definitions of $\max$ is similar. One is more general than the other, but not because it does anything smarter, but because you declared one of them to work on any `Ord` instance, while the other works only on the `RealFloat` instances.

By the way, `Ord` is more or less unavoidable here because if you have `max` you can define $\leq$ by
$$x \leq y \iff \max(x,y) = y.$$

Comment: Thanks, could you explain  $\leq$ by $$x \leq y \iff \max(x,y) = y.$$ a little bit more?

Comment: Take the real numbers and figure it out for your self: given any two numbers $x$ and $y$ when does $\max(x,y) = y$ hold? My explaining more won't really help -- it's better for your understanding if you spend some time thinking about it.